# Recursively mirroring a nested tuple in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I was trying to write a function that inputs a nested tuple and returns a tuple where all the elements are backwards, including those elements in other tuples (basically mirrors it).
So with this input:

```
((1, (2, 3)), (4, 5))
```

It should return:

```
((5, 4), ((3, 2), 1))
```

What I tried

```
def mirror(t):
    n = 1
    for i in t:
        if isinstance(i, tuple):
            mirror(i)
        if n == len(t):
            t = list(t)
            t = t[::-1]
            t = tuple(t)
        n += 1
    return t
```

Comment: You don't have to convert a tuple to a list to reverse it. `t = t[::-1]` works on tuples.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but I think it can be done relatively simply:

```
def mirror(data):
    if not isinstance(data, tuple):
        return data
    return tuple(map(mirror, reversed(data)))

>>> mirror(((1, (2, 3)), (4, 5)))
((5, 4), ((3, 2), 1))
```

This applies the `mirror` function to every element in the tuple, combining them into one new tuple in reverse order.

Answer (score 7):

The trickiness of this problem lies in the fact that `tuple` objects are immutable. One solution I can think of is recursively building each piece in the final reversed result, and then using `itertools` to join them together.

```
from itertools import chain

def mirror(data):
    r = []
    for t in reversed(data):
        if isinstance(t, tuple):
            t = mirror(t)
        r.append((t, ))

    return tuple(chain.from_iterable(r))
```

```
>>> mirror(((1, (2, 3)), (4, 5)))
((5, 4), ((3, 2), 1))
```

Thanks to Chris_Rands for the improvement.

---

Here's a simpler solution, courtesy PM2 Ring -

```
def mirror(t):
    return tuple(mirror(u) for u in t[::-1]) if isinstance(t, tuple) else t
```

```
>>> mirror(((1, (2, 3)), (4, 5)))
((5, 4), ((3, 2), 1))
```

It builds the result tuple recursively but using a gen comp.

Answer (score 4):

This type of structure, list inside list, is called hierarchical structure, which has property that the whole structure is assembled by small structures which resemble the large structure and are again assembled by even smaller structures.

Imaging a tree with branches resembled the whole tree and leaves at the tips. The first thing is to distinguish branches from leaves. If you see a branch, you treat it as a smaller tree (this naturally forms a recursion). If you see a leave, that means you get to the tip of the structure and you can return it (base case in recursion).

To go from bigger branch to smaller branches (deduction in recursion), there are generally two recursive approaches. The first is as what I did, splitting the branch to left and right and going along each of them. The other way is to map on each branch as what had been done by khelwood.

```
def mirror(T):
    if not isinstance(T, tuple):
        return T 
    elif T == ():
        return ()
    else:
        return mirror(T[1:]) + (mirror(T[0]),)

print(mirror(((1,(2,3)),(4,5))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't help myself :)

(This is a joke of course, but has the added benefit of reversing the digits ;)

```py
def rev(s, i, acc):
  if i == len(s):
    return acc

  ps = {'(': ')', ')': '('}

  return rev(s, i + 1, s[i] + acc) if not s[i] in ps else rev (s, i + 1, ps[s[i]] + acc)

def funnyMirror(t):
  return eval(rev(str(t), 0, ''))

print funnyMirror(((1, (2, 83)), (4, 5))) # ((5, 4), ((38, 2), 1))
```